# differences in heatmap/clustering defaults in R (heatplot versus heatmap.2)?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering, bioconductor

I'm comparing two ways of creating heatmaps with dendrograms in R, one with `made4`'s `heatplot` and one with `gplots` of `heatmap.2`. The appropriate results depend on the analysis but I'm trying to understand why the defaults are so different, and how to get both functions to give the same result (or highly similar result) so that I understand all the 'blackbox' parameters that go into this.

This is the example data and packages:

```
require(gplots)
# made4 from bioconductor
require(made4)
data(khan)
data <- as.matrix(khan$train[1:30,])
```

Clustering the data with heatmap.2 gives:

```
heatmap.2(data, trace="none")
```

[image]

Using `heatplot` gives:

```
heatplot(data)
```

[image]

very different results and scalings initially. `heatplot` results look more reasonable in this case so I'd like to understand what parameters to feed into `heatmap.2` to get it to do the same, since `heatmap.2` has other advantages/features I'd like to use and because I want to understand the missing ingredients.

`heatplot` uses average linkage with correlation distance so we can feed that into `heatmap.2` to ensure similar clusterings are used (based on: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2010-August/034757.html)

```
dist.pear <- function(x) as.dist(1-cor(t(x)))
hclust.ave <- function(x) hclust(x, method="average")
heatmap.2(data, trace="none", distfun=dist.pear, hclustfun=hclust.ave)
```

resulting in:
[image]

this makes the row-side dendrograms look more similar but the columns are still different and so are the scales. It appears that `heatplot` scales the columns somehow by default that `heatmap.2` doesn't do that by default. If I add a row-scaling to heatmap.2, I get:

```
heatmap.2(data, trace="none", distfun=dist.pear, hclustfun=hclust.ave,scale="row")
```

[image]

which still isn't identical but is closer. How can I reproduce `heatplot`'s results with `heatmap.2`? What are the differences?

*edit2*: it seems like a key difference is that `heatplot` rescales the data with both rows and columns, using:

```
if (dualScale) {
    print(paste("Data (original) range: ", round(range(data), 
        2)[1], round(range(data), 2)[2]), sep = "")
    data <- t(scale(t(data)))
    print(paste("Data (scale) range: ", round(range(data), 
        2)[1], round(range(data), 2)[2]), sep = "")
    data <- pmin(pmax(data, zlim[1]), zlim[2])
    print(paste("Data scaled to range: ", round(range(data), 
        2)[1], round(range(data), 2)[2]), sep = "")
}
```

this is what I'm trying to import to my call to `heatmap.2`. The reason I like it is because it makes the contrasts larger between the low and high values, whereas just passing `zlim` to `heatmap.2` gets simply ignored. How can I use this 'dual scaling' while preserving the clustering along the columns? All I want is the increased contrast you get with:

`heatplot(..., dualScale=TRUE, scale="none")`

compared with the low contrast you get with:

`heatplot(..., dualScale=FALSE, scale="row")`

any ideas on this?

Comment: To the last command, try adding `symbreaks=FALSE` to get similar coloring to `heatplot`. Still the column dendrograms need work.

Comment: @rmk thanks, not sure I understand what `symbreaks` does though. any ideas on the col dendrogram differences?

Comment: `symbreaks=FALSE` makes the coloring non-symmetric as seen in `heatplot` where the 0 value is not white in color (still a bit blue). As to the dendrogram, I think `heatamap.2` might be getting it right. Notice that in `heatmap.2`, EWS.T1 and EWS.T6 are side-by-side, whereas in `heatplot`, its EWS.T4 and EWS.T6. The former has a dist of 0.2, while the latter pair has 0.5.

Comment: @rmk: so is this a bug in `heatplot` then?

Comment: @rmk: could difference be explained by the `distEisen` function used inside `heatplot`? Unfortunately I can't think of a way to pass `heatplot` a correlation distance since it only takes something that's an argument to `dist()` and `dist()` does not have correlation distance. It would be possible if `heatplot()` took a correlation distance

Comment: This is quite interesting. I found this reference (http://bcb.dfci.harvard.edu/~aedin/courses/Bioconductor/EDA.pdf, see: 5. Cluster Analysis) that says `distEigen` is the same as correlation distance and `heatplot` calls `heatmap.2` internally. `distEigen` identically scores EWS.T6 closer to EWS.T15 and EWS.T1. Not sure what's going on with `heatplot`

Comment: Also, apparently, `heatplot` "dual-scales" its data. So, `?heatplot` suggests that you use `heatplot(data, dualScale=FALSE, scale="row")`

Comment: It says to turnoff dualScale only if you want "To reproduce older version of heatplot". I like the dual scaling. If I apply dual scaling code to data before calling heatmap.2 it gets closer but still not same. Not sure what is going on

Comment: More to the point, if I do `dualScale=False, and scale="row"`, the column dendrogram still does not look like it should

Comment: I edited my question to reflect these issues

Answer (score 42):

The main differences between `heatmap.2` and `heatplot` functions are the following:

1. heatmap.2, as default uses **euclidean** measure to obtain distance matrix and **complete** agglomeration method for clustering, while heatplot uses **correlation**, and **average** agglomeration method, respectively.
2. heatmap.2 computes the distance matrix and runs clustering algorithm before scaling, whereas heatplot (when `dualScale=TRUE`) clusters already scaled data.
3. heatmap.2 reorders the dendrogram based on the row and column mean values, as described [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/reorder.dendrogram.html).

Default settings (p. 1) can be simply changed within heatmap.2, by supplying custom `distfun` and `hclustfun` arguments. However p. 2 and 3 cannot be easily addressed, without changing the source code. Therefore `heatplot` function acts as a wrapper for heatmap.2. First, it applies necessary transformation to the data, calculates distance matrix, clusters the data, and then uses heatmap.2 functionality only to plot the heatmap with the above parameters.

The `dualScale=TRUE` argument in the heatplot function, applies only row-based centering and scaling ([description](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/scale.html)). Then, it reassigns the extremes ([description](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extremes.html)) of the scaled data to the `zlim` values:

```
z <- t(scale(t(data)))
zlim <- c(-3,3)
z <- pmin(pmax(z, zlim[1]), zlim[2])
```

---

In order to match the output from the heatplot function, I would like to propose two solutions:

**I - add new functionality to the source code `-> heatmap.3`**

The code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/tleja/7783150). Feel free to browse through revisions to see the changes made to heatmap.2 function. In summary, I introduced the following options:

- z-score transformation is performed prior to the clustering: `scale=c("row","column")`
- the extreme values can be reassigned within the scaled data: `zlim=c(-3,3)`
- option to switch off dendrogram reordering: `reorder=FALSE`

An example:

```
# require(gtools)
# require(RColorBrewer)
cols <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(10, "RdBu"))(256)

distCor <- function(x) as.dist(1-cor(t(x)))
hclustAvg <- function(x) hclust(x, method="average")

heatmap.3(data, trace="none", scale="row", zlim=c(-3,3), reorder=FALSE,
          distfun=distCor, hclustfun=hclustAvg, col=rev(cols), symbreak=FALSE)
```

[image]

---

**II - define a function that provides all the required arguments to the `heatmap.2`**

If you prefer to use the original heatmap.2, the `zClust` function (below) reproduces all the steps performed by heatplot. It provides (in a list format) the scaled data matrix, row and column dendrograms. These can be used as an input to the heatmap.2 function:

```
# depending on the analysis, the data can be centered and scaled by row or column. 
# default parameters correspond to the ones in the heatplot function. 
distCor <- function(x) as.dist(1-cor(x))
zClust <- function(x, scale="row", zlim=c(-3,3), method="average") {
    if (scale=="row") z <- t(scale(t(x)))
    if (scale=="col") z <- scale(x)
    z <- pmin(pmax(z, zlim[1]), zlim[2])
    hcl_row <- hclust(distCor(t(z)), method=method)
    hcl_col <- hclust(distCor(z), method=method)
    return(list(data=z, Rowv=as.dendrogram(hcl_row), Colv=as.dendrogram(hcl_col)))
}

z <- zClust(data)

# require(RColorBrewer)
cols <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(10, "RdBu"))(256)

heatmap.2(z$data, trace='none', col=rev(cols), Rowv=z$Rowv, Colv=z$Colv)
```

---

**Few additional comments regarding `heatmap.2(3)` functionality:**

- `symbreak=TRUE` is recommended when scaling is applied. It will adjust the colour scale, so it breaks around 0. In the current example, the negative values = blue, while the  positive values = red.
- `col=bluered(256)` may provide an alternative colouring solution, and it doesn't require RColorBrewer library.

Comment: Great and complete answer. Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wrote this up as a tutorial and added an extended version of TWL's zClust  to a package: http://stanstrup.github.io/heatmaps/